# When using Entity Framework, is Migrating necessary?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Since I already have a DB project in my solution, I was wondering can I leverage Entity Framework so that the Web Application may communicate with the database without having to do any migrations, or is migration necessary in order to use the Context of Entity Framework?

If migrating is not necessary then I also won't need the designer (edmx) file, I could just make my models and link them into my context right?

Comment: Migrations are optional, you can use the DB project to update your database. The EDMX goes with database first work flow, so you don't use them in code first. The issue you could run into is if you make code changes that are not in sync with the database you'll get exceptions or your relationships won't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary at all. 
I often write short solutions towards some databases where I just want to add some functionality on the fly. What I typically do is to just open SQL Server Object Explorer in VS2015, Expand the table I'm interested in, and just write a class on the fly, matching the fields that I need.

I.e for a table named "Classes" in the database, I would end up with a class in C#

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    // +other intersting fields
}
```

Then I simply create a DbContext class pointing to my database:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeClass> Classes{get; set;}

    public MyContext() : base("myConnectionString"){}
}
```

That's it. No need for migrations. It then simply just works :)